# How to move focus from RowsSupportFragment's row to next layout component?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-tv, leanback

I am using Android Leanback library for creating TV application. I have a layout which inflates Fragment (which is RowsSupportFragment) and below that there is button. So, when I scroll down to list of items in RowsSupportFragment after reaching to last item focus doesn't goes to button. 
I already have tried setting focusable(true), nextFocusDown(buttonId) etc.

I can see that RowsSupportFragment uses VerticalGridView internally to inflate list of items.

Do anybody has any idea about it?

here is my layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/listviewFragmentId"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:duplicateParentState="true"
android:nextFocusDown="@id/nextButtonId"
android:nextFocusForward="@id/nextButtonId" 
layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nextButtonId"/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/nextButtonId"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:duplicateParentState="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:text="Hello Next"/>

<// other items>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Note: 
Focus works correctly if I left/right align button.

Comment: Did you find the solution, I am facing the same problem. 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/67972525/4732846

Answer (score 0):

In My case this was work when i need focus on the any views

```
view.requestFocus();
```

Comment: issue is, as the focus is inside VerticalGridView items and so either I have check once the focus comes to last item than I have to request focus on button which is outside of RowsSupportFragment (means at activity level)

Answer (score 0):

In My case,i need focus on the any views on right outside of RowSupportFragment item so Working around with focusOutEnd,focusOutFront and other focus features in the Leanback Style solved my solution. 
like for requesting the focus to outside Button widget from RowSupportFragment, setting `<item name="focusOutEnd">true</item>`  in style worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed by following below steps.

**Step 1:**
Show menu or select other views when user press back button in remote. Then request focus for first item in the menu list.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(binding.llMenu.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        super.onBackPressed();
    }else {
        binding.llMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        binding.tvM1.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

**Step 2:**
You must have to override the click listener of those views or menus.

```
binding.tvM2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // your code
        Log.e("selected", "m2");
    }
});

binding.tvM2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // your code
        Log.e("selected", "m2");
    }
});
```

**Step 3:**
You can show some selection effects on focus change listener.

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
    if(b){
        view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(view.getContext(), R.anim.zoom_in));
    }else{
        view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(view.getContext(), R.anim.zoom_out));
    }
}
```

Now your remote(**d-pad**) will work as expected. When user press back button, it will forcefully focus on menus, and if user press back button again, it will exit from the app.